# Pass jquery data beween php pages

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a php class handler that I am using to create html output for my exercise-group.php page. However, this output (an array of items) is called on by using Jquery/AJAX and added to the page. However, there are some data values that are not displayed because they will be passed onto the exercise-single.php page. How can I gather these data values using jquery, load them into a php value and store them into a $_Session variable so the exercise-single.php can display these vars after the user clicks on on href tag. Sorry for the long post but this is the best I can do to explain what im trying to do.

Exercise.class.php

```
class Exercises {

public $vidSource;

public function displayExercises($result) {        
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                                         
             echo   "<div class='media'>" .
                    "<div class='media-object pull-left'>" .
                        "<a href='exercise-single.php'><img src='".$row["ImgResource"]."' class='img-responsive' alt='curl'></a>" .
                    "</div>" .
                    "<div class='media-body'>" .
                        "<h4 class='media-heading'><a href='#'>".$row["Exercise"]."</a></h4>" . 
                    "</div>" .
                "</div>";
$vidSource = $row["VidResource"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "<img src='https://media.giphy.com/media/cwTtbmUwzPqx2/giphy.gif' class='img-responsive'>"; 
        echo "<h3 class='media-heading'>No workouts exist for this muscle yet.<br>Please try another one.</a></h3>";
    }
 }
}
?>
```

ExerciseHandler.php

```
 <?php

include 'Exercises.class.php';
include 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['muscle'])){

$muscle =$_POST['muscle']; 

$connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises WHERE Muscle = '".$muscle."'";
$result = $connect->query($sql);

$exercises = new Exercises();

$exercises->displayExercises($result); 

}
?>
```

loadExercises.js

```
var muscle_id;

function getMuscle(clicked_muscle){
muscle_id = clicked_muscle;


$.post("ExerciseHandler.php", {
  muscle: muscle_id
},
function(data, status){
    $("#exercise-list").html(data);
});

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//Handler

```
 echo $exercises->displayExercises($result);
```

//Exercise Class

```
  public function displayExercises($result) {        
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      return json_encode(
       array(
       'status' => 'success',
       'data' => $result->fetch_assoc())
      );
   } else {
      return json_encode(
         array(
           'status' => 'error',
           'data' => array(
             'url' => "https://media.giphy.com/media/cwTtbmUwzPqx2/giphy.gif",
             'class' => 'img-responsive',
             'prompt' => 'Please try another one.'
           )
         )
      );
    }
  }
```

// Jquery Here

```
$.ajax({
  url : "ExerciseHandler.php",
  method : "POST",
  success : function(response){
    var result = JSON.parse(response);
    if(result.status == 'error'){
      $('img').attr('src',result[0].url);
      $('img').attr('class',result[0].class);
      $('h3').text(result[0].prompt);
    }else{
      $.each(result.data,function(index,value){
          // do the html append thing here
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to access data globally in all page per session you should create session like this in **while block** like this,

```
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             $_SESSION["name"] = $row["column_heading"];//create session                           
             echo   "<div class='media'>" .
                    "<div class='media-object pull-left'>" .
                        "<a href='exercise-single.php'><img src='".$row["ImgResource"]."' class='img-responsive' alt='curl'></a>" .
                    "</div>" .
                    "<div class='media-body'>" .
                        "<h4 class='media-heading'><a href='#'>".$row["Exercise"]."</a></h4>" . 
                    "</div>" .
                "</div>";
$vidSource = $row["VidResource"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "<img src='https://media.giphy.com/media/cwTtbmUwzPqx2/giphy.gif' class='img-responsive'>"; 
        echo "<h3 class='media-heading'>No workouts exist for this muscle yet.<br>Please try another one.</a></h3>";
    }
 }
```

this will work. and don't forget to start session in your php files. remember, you should start session on every page of your php files in which you are going to set or get session. You could do this by simply adding

**session_start();**

Comment: THANK YOU! Sorry for the late reply, been working a lot. I will try your solution asap